# Is it advisable to create war of elasticSearch and deploy it in tomcat or deploy elaticSearch independently?

Tags: java, tomcat, elasticsearch

recently i need to deploy elasticSearch as store to serve some part of the application. I already have tomcat server running in production for serving jaxrx application. 
I read at many location but didn't find convincing answer, weather to deploy elaticsearch as an independent server or include the war file of elasticsearch in webapps folder of tomcat.

I am using elasticSearch 6 with transportClient and tomcat version 8.

I am also new to tomcat, so if it is advisable to include it as war file in tomcat then please share how to do that.
Thanks.

Comment: Elasticsearch is best deployed independently. Embedding ES used to be supported but not anymore, so you can do it but at your own risks. Read this: https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-the-server

Comment: kind of convince, and thanks for replying.